# Combine Array(s) into single object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Currently I have 3 arrays:

```
var idArray = [13, 24, 35];    
var dateArray = [20181920, 20181120, 20172505];
var contentArray = ["content1", "content2", "content3"];
```

I would like to merge all the array into one object instead and I tried using for loop but got an error instead:

```
var finalObj = {};

for (var y = 0; y < dateArray.length; y++) { 
    finalObj[y].id = idArray[y];
    finalObj[y].date =  dateArrayArrange[y];
    finalObj[y].content =  contentArray[y];

}
```

The end result I want to achieve:

```
finalObj = [{id:13, date:20181920, content:"content1"},
          {id:24, date:20181120, content:"content2"},
          {id:35, date:20172505, content:"content3"}];
```

Comment: `finalObj` is an object but the result is an array of objects

Comment: Which error do you even get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `finalObj` is an array of objects, so you must initialise it as an array, like this :

```
var finalObj = [];
var idArray = [13, 24, 35];
var dateArray = [20181920, 20181120, 20172505];
var contentArray = ["content1", "content2", "content3"];

for (var y = 0; y < dateArray.length; y++) {
  finalObj.push(
    { id: idArray[y], date: dateArray[y], content : contentArray[y] }
  )
}
```

for the "pushing to final array" part, your code inside the loop may work if you add an extra `finalObj[y] = {}` to initialise it and so you have :

```
for (var y = 0; y < dateArray.length; y++) {
  finalObj[y] = {}  
  finalObj[y].id = idArray[y];
  finalObj[y].date = dateArray[y];
  finalObj[y].content = contentArray[y];
}
```

an it works but

```
  finalObj.push(
    { id: idArray[y], date: dateArray[y], content : contentArray[y] }
  )
```

is shorter and still readable i think :)

Answer (score 7):

`finalObj`  is an object you need to push the value in an array.Beside you can also use array `map` method which will return an array so there is no need to separately push the values to an array.

Use map method on any of the arrays and use the `index` to get the corresponding values from other array

```js
var idArray = [13, 24, 35];
var dateArray = [20181920, 20181120, 20172505];
var contentArray = ["content1", "content2", "content3"];

let m = idArray.map(function(item, index) {
  // here the map method will push the object to an 
  // array and will return that array
  return {
    id: item,
    date: dateArray[index],
    content: contentArray[index]
  }

})
console.log(m)
```

Comment: short and sweet, i love the map method :) +1

Comment: but not extendable ... and hard coded for variables and keys, as many other approaches.

Answer (score 2):

```
let newObjArray = idArray.map((value, index) => {
        return {
            id: value,
            date: dateArray[index],
            content:contentArray[index]
        }

    });
console.log(newObjArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm assuming you want an **Array Of Objects** which has the same length with the idArrays and others.

Here's some code for that:

```
var finalObjArray = [];

for (var y = 0; y < dateArray.length; y++) { 
    finalObjArray.push({
                       id: idArray[y],
                       date: dateArrayArrange[y],
                       content: contentArray[y]
    });

}
```

Basically you are adding objects to that array. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t a record of finalObj[y] when you set properties, so it return `undefined` instead.

To fix your problem, create a object with properties then push it to your array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
    var idArray = [13, 24, 35];    
    var dateArray = [20181920, 20181120, 20172505];
    var contentArray = ["content1", "content2", "content3"];
    
    var final = [];
    
    for (let y = 0; y < idArray.length; y++) { 
     let tmp = {};
        tmp.id = idArray[y];
        tmp.date =  dateArray[y];
        tmp.content =  contentArray[y];
        
        final.push(tmp);
    
    }
    
    console.log(final)
```

Note: `dateArrayArrange` does not even exist, I think you mean just `dateArray`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create objects and add them to the array. This code should work.

```
var idArray = [13, 24, 35];    
var dateArray = [20181920, 20181120, 20172505];
var contentArray = ["content1", "content2", "content3"];
var finalObj = [];

for (var y = 0; y < dateArray.length; y++) { 
    object = {};
    object.id = idArray[y];
    object.date =  dateArray[y];
    object.content =  contentArray[y];
    finalObj[y] = object;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could collect all key value pairs (for an arbitrary count) in an object and reduce the object while mapping the values.

```js
var id = [13, 24, 35],
    date = [20181920, 20181120, 20172505],
    content = ["content1", "content2", "content3"],
    result = Object
        .entries({ id, date, content })
        .reduce((r, [k, values]) => values.map((v, i) => ({ ...r[i], [k]: v })), []);
        
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

by using maps we can write a function which we can extend to any number of arrays and so on. the below function takes a minimum of three distinct fields.

```
function joinArrays(id, date, content,...array){
    const Arr = [...array];
    const newArr = new Array(Arr.length)
    for(let i=0; i<newArr.length;i++){
        newArr[i] ={}
    }
    Arr.map((rowArr,index)=>{
        rowArr.map((i,k)=>
            {
                key = arguments[index];
                let obj = {};
                obj[key] = i;
                newArr[k]=Object.assign(newArr[k],obj)}
        )
    }
    )
    console.log(newArr);
    return newArr;

}
target = joinArrays('id', 'date', 'content',idArray,dateArray,contentArray);
```